# Random direction without visually rotating shape opengl-es android

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, translate-animation

I want to be able to assign a shape a random direction to go in at a regular speed.

I tried assigning a random number to the x and y values of a translation but that caused the shape to sometimes move way too fast or just blip off the screen.

Is there a way to choose a random direction for a shape to move in without rotating the shape (at least as far as the user can tell)?

Also is there a way of re-genereating the random number when an event is called (ie: button click) which would allow a change in direction?

EDIT: Just checked. Using the rotate function with a random angle will shoot the square off in a random direction, but still is there a way to do this without altering the orientation of the shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want a shape to move in either the postive or negative x, y or z directions?

If you want this to be random then use the Random class. From this you can use Random.nextInt(1) which will either be 0 or 1, if the result is 0 then set the value to be -1.

The +1 or -1 is now used for your direction.

Now you know which way the object travels you can simply multiply this by the speed of your object

Here is some rough code

> Random rand = new Random(); int direction = rand.nextInt(1);
>
> if(direction == 0) direction = -1;
>
> Shape theShape.position.x += direction * theShape.speed

This may not be how your interface is setup (such as theShape.position or theShape.speed) but the idea is the same

After reading this again I think you are trying to rotate your shape lol, rotation is not just adding to the x and y values. Do you use matrices in your application? If not your should use trig to figure out what the x and y values will be after a rotation of x degrees

Comment: seems to run painfully slow on the emulator and I always get it going in the same direction =(

Comment: your going to need to use an actual phone if you want to make a game, the emulator is dead slow anyway. Only use it to test different screen dimensions/densities. Try rand.nextInt(2); I cant remeber if that will either be 0,1,2 or just 0,1